# Can I Leverage secure store for bitlocker encryptions?

Tags: sharepoint-online, secure-store

I fully accept that this is maybe a dumb question, but I don't mind being the fool.

**Is there any way that SharePoint's "*secure store*" functionality could be leveraged to store the bitlocker encryptions for an entire site/client/tennant?**

I accept that this may be a simple 'out of scope', "*no*", answer, since it's basically a SSO service of sorts (right?), but it's just something that occurred to me.

If it *is* a "*no*", (cheeky sub-question), is there an automated Azure AD bitlocker storage for O365/SharePoint stuff, that would hold this information for all users? Or could the "alternate secure store provider" mechanism that is built in to it be leveraged to securely manage bitlocker encryption?

Thanks,

Eliot

---

Things I know that may be relevant:

1. All SharePoint / OneDrive storage is bitlocker encrypted by default.
   secure store allows "*pluggable secure store mechanism that enables
   you to use alternate secure store providers*"
2. I've googled with no real correlations.
3. I've searched here for both phrases.
4. I am stupid!
5. I could be misreading [this](https://www.slideshare.net/d501159/data-encryption-technologies-in-microsoft-office-365) (via speed reading),but it would appear that there is, at least, some tangential connection between bitlocker encryption and how Azure holds the blob parts of secure store.

Answer (score 0):

Secure Store is meant for holding credentials to access external data sources, primary for BCS / BDC connections.  Storing bitlocker encryption information is not its intended purpose and I do not think that it is possible.

I'm not sure about using Azure AD or another Azure service to provide this functionality.

Comment: Cheers, Josh, much obliged.